# Python variable names

Tags: python, variables, scope

I was surprised today to find out that the following appears to be valid code in Python:

```
def foo(n):
  foo = n * 10
  return foo

foo(5)
```

What in Python allows for a variable name to match the name of the function it is in? Is it just some kind of scoping rule that helps to keep these 2 things separate? so Python simply considers a program's function namespace to be a completely separate animal from the program's variable name space?

(Note: I would hate to do this in my own programs as it's a tad confusing but c'est la vie as they say in France.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two separate scopes at play here: the global namespace, and the local namespace of the function.

- `foo` the function lives in the global namespace, because `def foo(n): ...` is executed at the top level of the module.
- `foo` the integer is a local variable inside the `foo()` function. The name only exists while `foo()` executes. When `return foo` is executed, the function ends and all local variables are cleaned up.

So yes, here these two can live next to one another perfectly fine.

Comment: Though you couldn't then call the function `foo` after creating the local variable `foo`.

Comment: Outside of the function? You can call `foo()` just fine! Locals don’t affect globals. Inside the function the local name `foo` is set to something different, making it harder to access the function object, but not impossible.